# Validator for file name with custom words between curly braces

Tags: c#, regex

I have regex:

```
[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$
```

and a filename:

```
test-file_name-5.pdf
```

And it works okay. But now I want to add something like this:

```
my-filename{time}.pdf
```

or this:

```
test{word}hello.pdf
```

and the regex should accept it.

If there is only opening/closing curly brace, it should fail. The braces could contain `a-Z0-9`.

I tried with RegExr but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[\w,\s-]+(?:(?:{[A-Za-z\d]+}[\w,\s-]*)?)*\.[A-Za-z]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # Assert position at the beginning of the string
[\w,\s-]+           # Beginning of the filename
(?:                 # Begin group
  (?:               #   Begin group
    {[A-Za-z\d]+}   #     Match {...} part
    [\w,\s-]*       #     Followed by optional characters
  )?                #   Make the group optional
)*                  # Repeat the group zero or more times
\.[A-Za-z]+         # Match the filename extension
$                   # Assert position at the end of the string
```

This matches:

```
test-file_name-5.pdf
my-filename{23m}.pdf
test{word1}hello{word2}xyz.pdf
test{word}hello.pdf
```

But doesn't match:

```
foo-filename{23m.pdf
foo-filename23m}.pdf
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aH0uN7/3)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to precise. {word} coud be in any place in text, not only at the end but before the dot. Exmaple: test{word}hello.pdf

Comment: Thanks alot. But I forgot to tell you I can put many {word} like: test{word1}hello{word2}xyz.pdf. And thats should be all :D

Comment: @zgnilec: Updated again. If you have any new questions, please feel free to ask a new one. Reference this one if necessary.